# Views and presenters directorys structure . 

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

For a winforms app, what do you think the ideal directory structure for views and presenters and your model are

Comment: ???  Did you hit submit too early?  If not I think you'll need a bit more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespace XXX.Core or XXX.BusinessObjects
-> models

namespace XXX.Views
-> views

namespace XXX.Controllers
-> controllers